# No option to set a static homepage in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I've just installed the newest WordPress (4.7.3). There is no option to set a static homepage, as shown below.

[image]

It should look like,

[image]

How do I set a set a static homepage in WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first, Please check switching another theme and also disable the plugins.

The cause might be **wordpress installation is probably corrupt**

You may want to check [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-find-static-front-page-setting/) & [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208154/option-to-set-static-front-page-disappeared-from-admin-reading-settings)

Comment: Thx. I re-installed my WordPress and deactivated all plugins, but the issue still exists. As mentioned in [Option to set static front page disappeared from admin reading settings](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208154/option-to-set-static-front-page-disappeared-from-admin-reading-settings), how do I turn on the homepage?

Comment: Is your homepage is in draft?

Comment: No, neither in draft nor in trash.

Comment: What is the type of homepage, custom link, post or page?

Comment: That's actually strange non of the solution is working in your case. Sorry to ask you to go through another step again. Please check [https://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/static-front-page-option-not-available] and follow the steps. I also wanted to have this sort out so desperately

Comment: Thx for ur constant help. I got my problem solved. My issue is caused by no available pages (I create new posts instead of pages).

Comment: I am so glad you just made it and found solution.